# cordova CLI not installed (ionic info) and vague error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic4

When I try to build all I get from ionic is:

[Error]: Command error.

That's all. I tried re-installing ionic, cordova, node and updating them according to the 'try-this-one' recommendations offered in the official and non-official documentation, but nothing seems to at least offer a hint about how to overcome this vague and poorly described error. Also tried updating npm but nothing seems to work or at least offer some extra info.

Comment: Which CLI command you used?

Comment: ionic cordova build android ... it also fails to remove platform and re-add with 'ionic cordova platfrom rm android'. Adding --verbose sadly doesn't add any extra info

Comment: `ionic info`? is that working?

Comment: Have you moved to the ionic root folder?

Comment: ionic info throws this: "Cordova CLI: Not installed" . I don't know what you mean by 'move to the ionic root folder'

Comment: Where you run these CLI? You need to move to the root of the project before you issue those CLI.

Comment: I run the command 'ionic info' and 'ionic cordova build android' in the root folder of the project... If I check the node/cordova/ionic versions in that folder, all seems to be OK ... but when I build I get the awesomely descriptive error "[ERROR]: Command error"

Comment: What about this? `ionic serve`

Comment: i get this with 'ionic serve': ERROR An error occurred while running subprocess npm

Comment: Remove everything and after that restart the machine and install it again.

Comment: Yeah... or quit using ionic I guess ... such a mess. Thanks anyway for your help! :)

Comment: Here I have meant, Ionic, nodeJs and all related things for Ionic.

Comment: I understand, they fail collectively. In my years of develeper never seen those behave the same in two different computers. So frustrating.

Comment: Hmm... Are you working on Windows 10 PC or?

Comment: No, i'm on Ubuntu. The original project was made in Windows and we are moving to Ubuntu... I mean, trying....

Comment: Did you have same issue on Windows 10 PC too?

Comment: We had but it was fixed due to the fact that the errors were at least descriptive enough to allow some reasearch. But this "ERROR: command error" has led me baffled.

Comment: Yes, I'm a Windows user. It seems the Ubuntu issue. You can log this issue on Ionic CLI repo here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!